# c# virtual method

Tags: c#, class, virtual

I have base class and Execute virtual method. I override execute method in derived class.
Is it possible to execute virtual method code in such flow?

1. virtual base method code execute
2. overridden method code execute
3. virtual base method code execute

Not sure if I have explained everything well but I hope to get explanation for my question :)

```
public abstract class ConverterBase
{
        public virtual void Execute()
{
try
{
 //1. Base class code    

// 2. Execute overridden method code.

}
finally
{
//3. Base class code
}
}
}

 public class Converter : ConverterBase
{
        public override void Execute()
{
//2. code
}
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, you want the [*template method pattern*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_method_pattern) here:

```
public abstract class ConverterBase
{
    public void Execute()
    {
        try
        {
            // Stuff
            ExecuteImpl();
        }
        finally
        {
            // Stuff
        }
    }

    protected abstract void ExecuteImpl();
}


public class Converter : ConverterBase
{
    protected override void ExecuteImpl()
    {
        // Stuff to execute within the parent's try block
    }
}
```

Comment: Jon, how does this allow the derived class to call the base class method before and after the derived functionality? Isn't this what the OP asked for?

Comment: @Jon, there is something wrong with your code. Converter.ExecuteImpl() will never hit ConverterBase.Execute();

Comment: @Tomas: It's not meant to - the idea is that public callers just call `Execute`, which will execute some code in the base class, then some code in the derived class, then the final bit of code in the base class. Isn't that what you wanted?

Comment: @Jamiec: I *suspect* the desired functionality is for the derived class to provide some bit of behaviour, which is then wrapped by functionality in the base class. The caller will just call `Execute`, and the rest will just do the right thing.

Comment: @Jon I got it. Never used such patter and was a little confused.

Answer (score 0):

It should be possible by calling `base.Execute()` from within your method.

More info: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hfw7t1ce(v=vs.71).aspx